# Can I debug jsp/servlet using mvn:jetty

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, maven-2

I can start the web server using mn:jetty, but don't know if I can debug using it. Is there any attach functionality in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to add the following VM arguments

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n
```

then you can connect to your VM as a remote app. See the official page for it :

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debugging+with+the+Maven+Jetty+Plugin+inside+Eclipse